# How can I log out from Ask Ubuntu?

Tags: support

I logged into Ask Ubuntu on a public computer.

I want to log out after use.

What should I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To log out of askubuntu or any stack exchange site:

1. Click the stack exchange logo (upper black circle)
2. Click log out (lower black circle)

[image]

Comment: I like those [Freehand Circles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775) :-D

Comment: I know, I should have used red :(